# свзяи в ER-диаграмме

Tags: база-данных, связывание-данных

Всем привет.
Есть база данных,и для неё нужно составить ER-диаграмму. Я примерно накидал,но не уверен в связях,а именно где проставить многие ко многим,один к одному и т.д. Можете посмотреть,и в случае ошибки подсказать?

База используется для курсовика по Help Desk. Т.е каждый пользователь с определённым уровнем прав(или статусом) заходит под своим логином и паролем,и составляет заявку в случае какой-либо неисправности.

[image: Примерная диаграмма]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Пользователей надо объединять в группы (многие ко многим).
2. Для категорий нужны права по группам пользователей (многие ко многим).
3. Реализация прав может быть сколь угодно сложной (или простой).
4. Не хватает истории заявок по жизненному циклу, по исполнителям и т.д. Может быть реализовано в виде системных и пользовательских комментариев (одна ко многим).
5. Исполнителей в принципе может быть несколько.
6. Иерархия заявок.
7. Жизненный цикл - граф. Для каждой категории свой.
8. Категории - иерархия
9. По необходимости дата создания, срок выполнения, акцептанты, трудозатраты...

Лишнее:

- Комментарий в заявках
- Статус в заявках (текущий статус брать надо из истории)
- Что такое статусы пользователей не совсем понятно

ЗЫ Если это учебное задание, отсекайте лишнее, берите нужное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне надо сделать именно с такой базой. Т.е фактически база уже есть,и надо лишь сделать для неё ER-диаграмму.
Я правильно понимаю,что на моей схеме все связи будут один к одному? Н-р: у одного пользователя может быть только один статус(или уровень прав),или у одной заявки может быть лишь один жизненный цикл

Comment: @ExzoTikFruiT судя по всему, да, один к одному.